# SQL Server reset sequence column

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table and I would like to reset the Code column sequence. The Code column is just an INT column.

**Current**

```
ID | Code
1  |    1
2  |    2
3  |    6
4  |   10
5  |   12
```

**Should be**

```
ID | Code
1  |    1
2  |    2
3  |    3
4  |    4
5  |    5
```

Comment: You want to update the column which isn't an `IDENTITY`? What is the connection to sequence/identity? Just update the column

Comment: Nope, it is just an int column

Comment: Why not `UPDATE x SET Code=ID` ? What is the logic behind the question?

Comment: Besides,  `SEQUENCE` is a specific object type in SQL Server.

Comment: It could be but what about a loop?

Comment: @Tico What about a loop? Why are you asking about a loop?

Comment: *reset the Code column sequence* - this means nothing to anyone without context - your question is not clear. Explain the logic you need to apply.

Comment: @Stu there is a simple example for what should be, anyway...

Comment: But you haven't told us why a simple update like Panagiotis suggests wouldn't work. Or even *if* it would work

Comment: @HoneyBadger you want an example, what if the IDs are 1, 2, 6, 8 would it work?

Comment: @Tico would what work? And what would you want `code` to be for those id's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update from a CTE (Common Table Expression) with a `ROW_NUMBER`

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ID, Code
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn
  FROM Your_Table
) 
UPDATE CTE
SET Code = rn;
```

That will update all records in the table.
To only correct those that need correcting, an extra criteria helps.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ID, Code
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn
  FROM Your_Table
) 
UPDATE CTE
SET Code = rn
WHERE (Code IS NULL OR Code != rn);
```

Comment: Why do that, instead of a simple `SET Code = ID`? We don't know what's going on

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos A column with a identity can have gaps. if records were deleted for example. Or a rollback happened.

Comment: @LukStorms we don't know if gaps are a problem (they should never be), because OP isn't clear.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Sometimes you just try to read between the lines and provide an answer that's potenionally off the mark. If the OP then later makes things clear and it turns out you were overthinking or underthinking it then the anwer can be changed or deleted.  And updating with the same value as the id doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: @LukStorms personally, I prefer to withhold an answer until the question is clear. I've learned that whether or not something makes sense to me is irrelevant

Comment: And to be the most efficient as possible, the query should include a WHERE clause to avoid updating rows that do not change. E.g., `where code <> rn;`  Add null handling if needed. In OP's sample data, the first two rows do not change so there is no reason to update them.

Comment: @Smor Well, I suppose the OP has a bigger table in reality. So it was worth adding that to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could just run an update using the window function as below

```
update t 
set code = t1.rownum
from 
[yourtable] t 
inner join 
(select id,row_number()over(order by id) as rownum
from [yourtable])t1
on t.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET Code = ID WHERE 1
// you can filter with Where
```

Im wrong?

Comment: It could work but what if the IDs are: 1, 2, 6, 7, 10?